# Null exception after calling Post Request

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, client-server

I am building a web api on asp.net. I make requests through client and server. GET and DELETE methods are working properly. When i make POST or PUT i get an error "Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error)." 
Client:
[image]

[image]

Server:
[image]

I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RsCP-xyW1k) tutorial. 
Why i get a null object (Employee)?

Comment: where is _Employees being assigned?

Comment: At EmployeeModel class on server. 
public static List<Employee> _Employees = new List<Employee>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how but when i built a new project the error dissapeared... I used the exact same files and classes.

Answer (score 0):

If `AddEmployee` is an endpoint, then you may need to put the `[FromBody]` attribute on the parameter.

If it's not an endpoint, then I don't see where `AddEmployee` is being called. But it looks like the `employee` parameter is the one that is null. Look up the stack trace, and I bet you'll find someplace where employee is not being set.

Comment: Already tried the [FromBody] attribute. I can't find anything on stack. :/ Thank you for your answer